# Removing undefined from javascript output

Tags: javascript, node.js

Running the following script in javascript or nodejs or any other javascript environment prints:

```
undefined
0
1
2
3
4
```

Script:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    var a = function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        },i*1000);
    };
    a(i);
}
```

Where does the `undefined` comes from?

Answer (score 2):

When using a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) environment, the expression you enter is evaluated and its result is returned.

In this case, the result is `undefined`. It's a side effect of the REPL, it's not part of the output of your code.

Comment: any idea how to remove it from even inside an REPL?

Comment: @SurenderThakran You can't, and there is no reason to want to

Comment: it is actually an interview question someone asked me, so was wondering. I tried: for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    var a = function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        },i*1000);
    };
    var b = a(i);} which didn't worked. I also tried: for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    var a = function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        },i*1000); return null;
    };
    a(i);} which just replaced undefined with null

Answer (score 2):

If you’re running it from the REPL, `undefined` is the completion value of the expression, which is `a(4)`. `a` doesn’t return anything, so its return value is `undefined`, and the REPL prints that. It is not passed to `console.log` and won’t appear if you run it as a standalone script.

Comment: The phantom console `undefined`. *shakes fist*

Comment: @minitech okz, but how do i remove it from even inside an REPL?